# How change back url of your site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I accidentally added **www** before url of my local running site for some plugin. than I couldn't access to site again because obviously my local server which is **open server** don't have www prefix before main path. So I changed back both in my **wp-config.php** and even in **mySql** database. In bot places they show the url path without www , but now when I press my site name in admin part its again add back this www so in result browser shows site not found. Can I somehow get rid of **www** from the path? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have made absolutely sure that ALL domain/URL related records in the database are updated so that there is no www prefix anywhere (especially the wp_options table), the problem most likely lies with the .htaccess file.

For a quick test, find the file called .htaccess in the web root folder of the site and just rename it and then try. If that works, look for something like the following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you find this, change it as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Finally, change the file name back to .htaccess and it should work fine.

*Edit*: In some cases, it may be necessary to clear browser cache/cookies and/or restart the browser/reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I chnged the name of .htaccess it was the same. Just in case also changed RewriteCond and RewriteRule , but it was the same